# How to add "active" class for the currently active sticky menu element?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, sticky

I have a sticky menu which works perfectly, but I want to add some additional functionality to it. Basically, I need to add "active" class to menu item which is user currently browsing.

Live demo is located [here](https://www.metroguides.net/ru/cities/moskovskij-metropoliten-moskva-rossiya).

I'm currently using [StickUp](https://lirancohen.github.io/stickUp/#home) framework to achieve this and my menu is based on this code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav role="navigation" id="access">
    <a class="skip-link icon-reorder" href="#menu">Навигация</a>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a class="icon-home" href="#gallery">Галерея</a></li>
      <li><a class="icon-home" href="#metromap">Карта</a></li>
<li><a class="icon-home" href="#workinghours">Часы работы</a></li>
<li><a class="icon-group" href="#fares">Стоимость проезда</a></li>
<li><a class="icon-picture" href="#advices">Советы</a></li>
<li><a class="icon-envelope-alt" href="#links">Полезные ссылки</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
</div>
```

This is the JS that makes my menu sticky:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
              //initiating jQuery
              jQuery(function($) {
                $(document).ready( function() {
                  //enabling stickUp on the '.navbar-wrapper' class
                  $('.moduletable').stickUp({
                itemHover: 'active'
                  });
                });
              });
            </script>
```

Comment: you want to get this class on click, or when scrolling

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I thought it could be achieved by the same code. I need both if possible.
When user clicks on menu item page scrolls down to this particular menu item and it is becoming active (here we're adding "active" class).

Comment: SO will help you with what you wrote but we won't write code for you.

Comment: Hey Rob. What additional information should I post? My js and html code is on the top.

Comment: Why not just use a small script and target with pseudo-selecters?

Comment: @Nick Babkin based on this sticky nav plugin, you need to add `parts` object  with `id's` of your sections  https://lirancohen.github.io/stickUp/#one-pager

Comment: I've seen the parts thing from Liran website, but is it possible to achieve with my own customized menu?